# BlackBerry: [un]checking HTML checkboxes with JS not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms, blackberry, mobile-phones

I am trying to check and uncheck an `<input type="checkbox" />` by adding and removing the `checked="checked"` attribute using javascript (jQuery). It works great in Firefox & IE. Adding and removing `disabled="disabled"` works perfectly. But with checked, neither clearing nor adding the attribute does anything.

I'm writing in XHTML 1.0 Strict--I tried switching everything around to HTML 4.1 and just using `checked` with no equals sign or value, and it still didn't work.

I'm working on Eclipse with the BlackBerry 9000 Simulator 4.6.0.200904091609-212.

Any ideas? A bug? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the DOM object's `checked` property to `false`, the old-fashioned way?

Comment: sounds promising. A few searches and I'm not sure exactly how to do this--could you suggest a way either with jQuery or plain old javascript? thanks.

Comment: There was a time when you could control the DOM *without* jQuery. These things still work. ;-) http://www.web-source.net/web_development/controlling_checkboxes.htm